# How to grep a sequence and create a different file?

Tags: bash, grep, seq

I have a output (geom_dist_output) file from my previous calculation, which contains "Modo:   1", "Modo:   2", "Modo:   3" upto "Modo:   90". There are several points between "Modo:   1" and "Modo:   2", so to grep a data I am using:

For Mode-1;

```
grep -A100000 "Modo:    1"  geom_dist_output | grep -B100000 "Modo:    2" | egrep -v "Modo:    2" > Mode-1
```

For Mode-2;

```
grep -A100000 "Modo:    2"  geom_dist_output | grep -B100000 "Modo:    3" | egrep -v "Modo:    3" > Mode-2
```

Similarly up to 90.

Is there any way or sequence, where I can grep different Mode-i (i=1,2..90) and create a different files.

Comment: Well bash comes with for loops, so you should be able to do that, but it won't be very efficient especially with large files, because grep needs the loop over the whole file every time. Consider writing a small script in a programming language like python to do what you want instead.

Comment: [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output and tag your question with `awk` and you'll get a good answer. If you're considering using a shell loop then make sure to read https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/133219 first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a single Mode-$i:

```
sed -n "/Modo:    $i/,/Modo:/{/Modo:/b;p}" geom_dist_output >Mode-$i
```

Here `sed` prints the lines from `Modo:    $i` to a following `Modo:` except the `Modo:` lines.

If you want all Mode-1..90 files at once and if you have a [`csplit`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/csplit-invocation.html) with the `--suppress-matched` option:

```
csplit -fMode- --suppress-matched geom_dist_output /Modo:/ '{*}'
```